# How to generate Code_products in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**How to create invoice number as below required?**

Invoice format **DP1411-0001** it contain three piece.

- **DP** = type of invoice
- **14** = year of create invoice
- **11** = month of creating invoice
- **0001** = number of invoice that generate by invoice amount

Example

- DP1411-0001
- DP1411-0002
- DP1411-0003
- ...........
- DP1411-000n

But I have not any idea or logic to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat everything,
When generating Invoice get the information about whether it is DP or something store it into some variable.
Get the year and month and store it some variable and finally concat everything...

if you want something else please be specific.